# Sorry, there's a problem with nodist. When trying to initilise a new npm project

Tags: node.js, github, npm, nvm, nodist

I am following the following guide from GitHub [Here](https://github.com/Huddly/sdk/tree/master/examples/azure_iot) but when I enter `npm init` I keep getting the error:

> Sorry, there's a problem with nodist. Couldn't resolve node version
> spec %s: %s 11.13.0 Couldn't find any matching version

I have followed the previous steps and set the version to `v10.15.3`, but the error keeps appearing every time I use `nvm`. I have also set the version to `v11.13.0`, as this is what the error is requesting, but I still get the same result. Installed versions include: `11.13.0, 10.16.0, 10.15.3, 8.11.2, 0.12.0`

Any help with this would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

There are several reasons which can cause this problem:

1. If due to some reasons like poor internet connection your node or npm versions you have downloaded are corrupted. In this case you need to remove the files `.npm-version-global` and `.node-version-global` as well as empty the folders `v`, `v-64` and `npmv` within the installation of the Nodist folder.
2. You have a local version of the node specified in `.node-version` file in the root directory of your project. In this case you need to install that version by `nodist local XXX` where XXX is the version of the node in `.node-version` file.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem was that **I had a node version specified in my code repo that didn't match the node version installed on my machine**. I needed the updated node version on my machine, so

1. I opened file explorer to the root of my repo.
2. I opened `.node-version` and edited the version number to the updated version I needed.
3. `npm cache clean --force` to start with a fresh cache. (Note: [Others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51607362/please-run-npm-cache-clean) have said that `npm cache clean --force` is outdated, but this command worked for both my teammate and for me using npm version 6.9.0.)
4. `npm install` to reinstall my node modules.
5. `npm run build` and I had a clean build. Yay!

Answer (score 0):

For Node 18 and npm 8.19.1, I found the advice at https://github.com/nullivex/nodist/issues/252#issuecomment-1170897428 useful.

I was getting cb.apply errors, and problems with @npmcli/arborist and libnpmfund, but I created those two links from the list.

I was using npx. This installs an old (v 5.8) version of npm inside its node_modules. That npm contains graceful-fs inside its node_modules. The cb.apply error was coming frome graceful-fs's polyfill.js.

I installed the latest version of graceful-fs, and copied the newer polyfill.js into the abovementioned (child of npm's) graceful-fs. This seemed to fix the problem for me.