# Angular 9 ng new myapp gives error The Schematic workflow failed

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, angular9

I have angular 9 installed

> Angular CLI: 9.0.1 Node: 13.8.0 OS: win32 x64
>
> Angular: ... Ivy Workspace:
>
> ### Package                      Version
>
> @angular-devkit/architect    0.900.1
>   @angular-devkit/core         9.0.1
>   @angular-devkit/schematics   9.0.1
>   @schematics/angular          9.0.1
>   @schematics/update           0.900.1
>   rxjs                         6.5.3

Everytime i try to create a new project with ng new, I'm getting the message

> Installing packages...npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
>   npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...pm-signature":"-----B'
>   npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: 
>   npm ERR! C:\Users\Lijo John Daniel\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2020-02-12T09_52_57_342Z-debug.log
>   × Package install failed, see above. 
>   The Schematic workflow failed. See above.

I have tried re-installing angular and even node but issue still remains

My OS version is Win 10 v.1909 build 18363.592. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Try this Answer Link for resolving this issue
https://stackoverflow.com/a/67455400/10538842

Answer (score 26):

First ,verify your NPM cached memory

```
npm cache verify
```

then try :

```
npm cache clean --force
npm install –g @angular/cli@latest 
ng new <YourProjectName>
```

If the problem persists, then try the following

```
npm cache clean --force
npm update
ng new <YourProjectName>
```

###### NOTE

As @0210vidit said in the comment below:

**do not use dash(-) or (.) in naming**

Answer (score 15):

Try to **clean** the npm cache using:

```
npm cache clean --force
```

then should it works now,

```
ng new my-app
```

Answer (score 8):

I had similar issue and installing yarn or clearing cache didn't help.
I removed '-' from my app name and it worked

**Error :**

```
ng new first-app
```

**Solved:**

```
ng new firstapp
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: using "."  like  Project.Web  in project name also may result in a error

Answer (score 6):

This issue is reported for angular 9 and multiple geo-locations are facing this problem.
refer https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/16944

to proceed you can bring you angular version to 8 with below steps

ng --version

npm uninstall -g @angular/cli

npm cache clean --force

npm install -g @angular/cli@8.0.0

ng --version

Answer (score 5):

I had this issue since yesterday, tried all of this and it did not work. Then I installed yarn, and configured angular cli to use yarn as the packagemanager by running this command
`ng config -g cli.packageManager yarn`, and it worked.

Comment: got this error: Error: Schema validation failed with the following errors:
  Data path "/cli" must NOT have additional properties(completion).

Answer (score 3):

First try the following

```
npm cache clean --force
npm install -g @angular/cli
ng new <project-name>
```

If the problem persists, then try this (*this eventually solved my workflow issue*)

```
npm cache clean --force
npm update
ng new <project-name>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

In my case i've tried everything with npm and no way out.

But with yarn worked with no worries!

I'm a windows user but you can find how to install in other OS in yarn website!

1st - i downloaded yarn from his website [yarn](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install#windows-stable)

2nd - installed the global package with vs terminal: 
      yarn global add @angular/cli

3rd - still in vs terminal set: ng config -g cli.packageManager yarn

4th - i created my app: ng new myapp

5th - so you know te rest ...

Worked fine to me!

Answer (score 3):

I removed my previous solution as I somehow got hung up on the uninstalled node_modules part and presented a solution that probably wouldn't have been relevant. Here is an alternate solution that might work for you...

Open a new terminal and run node -v and then `npm -v` to make sure you are running compatible versions: "Node 8.9 or higher, together with NPM 5.5.1 or higher"
Uninstall your current Global Angular cli `npm uninstall -g @angular/cli`
Run npm cache verify
Re-Install Angular CLI npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
Close your terminal window (just because).
Open a new terminal window, browse to where you want your new project and try the 'ng new` command again.

Comment: This works for me. At the time of this comment, I think the latest version of angular cli is `11.2.1`.

Answer (score 3):

This work fine top of all solutions and worked for me on Windows 10...
Go to vs code new terminal type the following in order

1. npm install --global yarn
2. yarn global add @angular/cli
3. ng config -g cli.packageManager yarn
4. ng new projectname

this will fix the issue..

Comment: I tried all the other options. But this one worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

1. `npm uninstall -g @angular/cli`
2. `npm cache clean --force`
3. `npm install -g @angular/cli`

then should it works now,

```
ng new my-app
```

Comment: this is bug I believe

Comment: might be but got fixed for me by doing this way .

Answer (score 1):

I got it working, first I installed angular 8 then ran npm install -g @angular/cli@latest.
It updated to angular 9 and now i'm able to create new projects. Thank you all for your consideration

Answer (score 1):

Angular 9 `ng new myapp` gives error **The Schematic workflow failed......**

Firstly, uninstall Angular: `npm uninstall -g @angular/cli`

After uninstall, you should do clean Angular cache: `npm cache clean --force`

After this, you should do re-install Angular globally: `npm install -g @angular/cli`

And check the version: `ng --version`

Now you can create your app: `ng new your-app`

Answer (score 1):

Only solution worked for me

1. Clear NPM cache + uninstall node
2. Install Node.js
3. Install Angular CLI

This will cost you some Internet data, but better option than wandering around for nothing! Keep a back up of Node.js. Useful next time.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the simple way, i am sure it will help because this is the error with *package installation failed*.

Skip node packages for now and use this command to create new app.

```
ng new YourAppName --skip-install
```

after that just go into your project directory and run npm install it will install all required packages for you.

Comment: This command helps to install Angular 10 in Windows 7 64bit.

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with this type of issue for a while.

Adding the following environment variable to your user account should solve the issue, adding a temporary cache option.

- name: npm_config_cache
- value: /tmp/empty-cache

More information concerning [npm-config](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config) .

Comment: I've had this issue because of not having Git installed

Comment: My experience was pointing to a npm install cache issue (credit to [infin80](https://stackoverflow.com/users/256509/infin80) and to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54100103/14183500) for teaching me about using the --cache option). To solve the npm install issue I had during the creation of a new angular app, I found that the environment variable npm_config_cache was setting the option transparently.

Answer (score 1):

Always update to the latest `LTS` version of Nodejs before using angular cli current version.

Answer (score 0):

as a temporary fix you can manually install "error-ex" module directly from GitHub then install your dependencies as mentioned here facebook/create-react-app#8465 (comment)

$ npm i https://github.com/Qix-/node-error-ex

$ npm i

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue then I navigate to the file **.angular-config** path **C:\Users\username** and change **"packageManager" : "npm"**

`{
  "version": 1,
  "cli": {
    "analytics": "_________",
    "packageManager": "npm"
  }
}`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, after a lot of search and two day of trying many ways, I finally solved my problem by installing codelyzer.
first run this command in cmd:

```
npm install -g codelyzer
```

then run:

```
ng new yourProject
```

Comment: hello @Maryam, It is nice that you get your solution but it will help us if you can `post the source` from where your problem is solved, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This must work because I had a similar problem

1. `npm install -g @angulat/cli`
2. `npm install mkdirp`
3. `npm cache verify`
4. close terminal and open again
5. `ng new your project name`

if it doesn't work, turn your firewall off and do them again. I bet it will work.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, this command resolved my problem:

`ng config -g cli.packageManager yarn`

Comment: Please don't add _"thanks"_ as answers. They don't actually provide an answer to the question, and can be perceived as noise by its future visitors. Once you [earn](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/146472) enough [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you will gain privileges to [upvote answers](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) you like. This way future visitors of the question will see a higher vote count on that answer, and the answerer will also be rewarded with reputation points. See [Why is voting important](http://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote).

Answer (score 0):

**Follow this way to solve this issue**

1. Open a new terminal and run `node -v` and then `npm -v` to make sure you are running compatible versions: "Node 8.9 or higher, together with NPM 5.5.1 or higher"
2. Uninstall your current Global Angular cli `npm uninstall -g @angular/cli`
3. Run `npm cache verify`
4. Re-Install Angular CLI `npm install -g @angular/cli@latest`
5. Close your terminal window.
6. Open a new terminal window, browse to where you want your new project and try the 'ng new` command again.

Answer (score 0):

This issue arises mostly because of the npm cache still keeping this error. All you need to do is to force clean the npm cache and try creating your app again.

```
npm cache clean --force
ng new myapp
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error. Before you reinstall the Angular CLI you have to check your internet connection and its speed. In my case, the error has occurred because my internet connection was interrupting. I could resolve that issue after I fixed my connection issue.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure **cli** is in a small case and package looks like `@angular/cli` during installation. I have followed this in some tutorial to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Please install new node js updated version and angular CLI as well.
will surely solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

1. npm cache clean --force
2. ng new my-app --skip-install
3. cd my-app
4. npm i
5. ng serve

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when updating `npm` to `7.x.x`

So if you want to use `angular12` based on [angular-cli-node-js-typescript-compatiblity-matrix](https://gist.github.com/LayZeeDK/c822cc812f75bb07b7c55d07ba2719b3) version of node and npm should be like this :

node : `12.13.x - 14.15.x`
npm :  `6.x.x - 7`

I used `nvm` for mange version of node

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, which I solved like this:

```
npm install -g npm@latest
npm cache clean --force
ng new project-name
```

Comment: Hi Cassey, welcome to SO! A short comment about the script and how it addresses the problem would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Hi try all above suggestion clearing the cache, reinnstalling ng, ...
Restarting my server did the trick..

Answer (score -1):

I followed [this link](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/17198#issuecomment-598079047) and got my issue resolved.

You can also follow [this link](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/17198#issuecomment-611977620). This also resolves the issue.

in the short first link says:

`npm cache clean --force
npm i -g @angular/cli`

the second link says:

`ng new angular --skip-install
cd angular
npm i
ng serve`