# The Schematic workflow failed. See above. on multiple commands

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-cli

When using angular cli I keep getting the error:

```
Package install failed, see above.
The Schematic workflow failed. See above
```

Most answers I find on the web do not seem to help me. Specifically I tried most of the answers here:

[Angular 9 ng new myapp gives error The Schematic workflow failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60185874/angular-9-ng-new-myapp-gives-error-the-schematic-workflow-failed)

When I try 'ng new', the only answer that helped me was to add --skip install and then run 'npm install'.

But then I keep getting the same error when trying:

```
ng add @angular/material
```

I tried my luck adding --skip-install but got:

```
Unknown option: '--skip-install'
```

It seems that the material package did install, but the schematic is not running all the way to its end. I get the error after the output:

```
UPDATE package.json (1267 bytes)
```

I also have the same message when running 'ng update'.

Is there a way to analyze the schematics that I am running so I can get more information where exactly this error occurs? Otherwise, anyone has any new idea not listed in the above link?

Here is the output of 'ng --version':

```
Angular CLI: 11.2.3
Node: 14.16.0
OS: linux x64

Angular: 11.2.4
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, router
Ivy Workspace: Yes

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1101.4
@angular-devkit/build-angular   0.1101.4
@angular-devkit/core            11.1.4
@angular-devkit/schematics      11.2.3
@angular/cdk                    11.2.3
@angular/cli                    11.2.3
@angular/material               11.2.3
@schematics/angular             11.2.3
@schematics/update              0.1102.3
rxjs                            6.6.6
typescript                      4.1.5
```

Answer (score 1):

Problems solved by downgrading NodeJS from 14 to 12. It seems that Angular 11 is not working well with NodeJS 14.